# In NetBeans, how to turn word-wrap off for specific file types?

Tags: netbeans, word-wrap

Netbeans (7.0) has a nice word-wrap feature (tools|options|formatting|linewrap).

However, I would like to have word-wrap on when looking at my code files, but have it off when looking at .txt files.

Is there an option to do this or some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 2):

In tools|options|formatting you can select Language:Java. There's a Line Wrap property just for Java files.